# Using ROW_NUMBER() within my sql on Union

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2005

Basically im trying to do a pagination on an sql query that consists of a union of several tables. After reading several similar answers on this topic, my query looks like this :

```
SET @PageSelect = '
SELECT CATALOG,
       ProductID,
       CreateDate,
       Brand,
       Model,
       Category,
       YearOfManufacture,
       PriceOriginal,
       PriceOriginalUnit,
       EngineOutput,
       Country,
       LOCATION,
       ReadOut,
       AttachmentPath1,
       AttachmentPath2,
       AttachmentPath3,
       AttachmentPath4,
       AttachmentPath5,
       AttachmentPath6,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreateDate DESC, ProductID) AS RowNumber
FROM
  ( SELECT ''Agriculture'' AS CATALOG,
                        ProductID,
                        CreateDate,
                        Brand,
                        Model,
                        QCategoryName AS Category,
                        YearOfManufacture,
                        PriceOriginal,
                        PriceOriginalUnit,
                        EngineOutput,
                        Country,
                        LOCATION,
                        MeterReadoutHours AS ReadOut,
                        AttachmentPath1,
                        AttachmentPath2,
                        AttachmentPath3,
                        AttachmentPath4,
                        AttachmentPath5,
                        AttachmentPath6
   FROM Product1 WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE (Status = 8)
   UNION ALL SELECT ''Cargo-Transport'' AS CATALOG,
                                     ProductID,
                                     CreateDate,
                                     Brand,
                                     Model,
                                     QCategoryName AS Category,
                                     YearOfManufacture,
                                     PriceOriginal,
                                     PriceOriginalUnit,
                                     EngineOutput,
                                     Country,
                                     LOCATION,
                                     MeterReadoutKilometers AS ReadOut,
                                     AttachmentPath1,
                                     AttachmentPath2,
                                     AttachmentPath3,
                                     AttachmentPath4,
                                     AttachmentPath5,
                                     AttachmentPath6
   FROM product6 WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE (Status = 8)
   UNION ALL SELECT ''Construction'' AS CATALOG,
                                  ProductID,
                                  CreateDate,
                                  Brand,
                                  Model,
                                  QCategoryName AS Category,
                                  YearOfManufacture,
                                  PriceOriginal,
                                  PriceOriginalUnit,
                                  EngineOutput,
                                  Country,
                                  LOCATION,
                                  MeterReadoutHours AS ReadOut,
                                  AttachmentPath1,
                                  AttachmentPath2,
                                  AttachmentPath3,
                                  AttachmentPath4,
                                  AttachmentPath5,
                                  AttachmentPath6
   FROM Product2 WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE (Status = 8)
   UNION ALL SELECT ''Forestry'' AS CATALOG,
                              ProductID,
                              CreateDate,
                              Brand,
                              Model,
                              QCategoryName AS Category,
                              YearOfManufacture,
                              PriceOriginal,
                              PriceOriginalUnit,
                              EngineOutput,
                              Country,
                              LOCATION,
                              MeterReadoutHours AS ReadOut,
                              AttachmentPath1,
                              AttachmentPath2,
                              AttachmentPath3,
                              AttachmentPath4,
                              AttachmentPath5,
                              AttachmentPath6
   FROM Product3 WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE (Status = 8)
   UNION ALL SELECT ''Groundscare'' AS CATALOG,
                                 ProductID,
                                 CreateDate,
                                 Brand,
                                 Model,
                                 QCategoryName AS Category,
                                 YearOfManufacture,
                                 PriceOriginal,
                                 PriceOriginalUnit,
                                 EngineOutput,
                                 Country,
                                 LOCATION,
                                 MeterReadoutHours AS ReadOut,
                                 AttachmentPath1,
                                 AttachmentPath2,
                                 AttachmentPath3,
                                 AttachmentPath4,
                                 AttachmentPath5,
                                 AttachmentPath6
   FROM Product4 WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE (Status = 8)
   UNION ALL SELECT ''MaterialHandling'' AS CATALOG,
                                      ProductID,
                                      CreateDate,
                                      Brand,
                                      Model,
                                      QCategoryName AS Category,
                                      YearOfManufacture,
                                      PriceOriginal,
                                      PriceOriginalUnit,
                                      EngineOutput,
                                      Country,
                                      LOCATION,
                                      MeterReadoutHours AS ReadOut,
                                      AttachmentPath1,
                                      AttachmentPath2,
                                      AttachmentPath3,
                                      AttachmentPath4,
                                      AttachmentPath5,
                                      AttachmentPath6
   FROM Product5 WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE (Status = 8)) AS BasicSource
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ' + CAST(@inPage * @inPageSize - @inPageSize + 1 AS NVARCHAR) + ' AND ' + CAST(@inPage * @inPageSize AS NVARCHAR) + ' ORDER BY RowNumber'
```

,but i get an error on my Row Number : `Invalid column name 'RowNumber'.`

Could someone explain what am I doing wrong ?

I have an optimisation issue. I would like to make pagination ( take only 25->100 items from the unions of the tables ) . But in this particular case ... it gets all the results from the union ( ~400k ) and that makes it slow

Answer (score 1):

When you name a column in the `SELECT` clause of a query using `AS` you cannot refer to it by that name in the `WHERE` clause.

To reference the `ROW_NUMBER()` you must wrap that whole thing up as a subquery. Then in the outer query's `WHERE` clause you can refer to `RowNumber`.

The same error can be seen if you try to run:

```
SELECT 1 AS Number 
WHERE Number = 1
```

You get Invalid column name 'Number'. But if you Wrap it in another `SELECT` you can use the column name.

```
SELECT Number AS AnotherName FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS Number 
) Numbers
WHERE Number = 1
```

If you changed the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE AnotherName = 1`, you'd get the same error again, because the query parser does not yet know you have named it `AnotherName` in your query, it only knows the column names of the sub query. This is because when it evaluates the query it filters the result set based on the `WHERE` clause before it `SELECT`s the relevant data.